# Jetpack Compose scrollable row with equal weight components

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

With the below code the middle text is forced into the second row (image1). I would like text to stay in the same row regardless of it's length. I tried removing weight() parameter and adding the `horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())` to `Row()` but then texts don't fill the max width when their short. The texts are dynamic, so if they short enough, they should all fit into the screen (each of them taking as much space, as they need - image 2). And when even one text is long, I would like to make the whole row horizontally scrollable (image3).

```
@Composable
fun RowOfChips() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(start = 24.dp, end = 24.dp, top = 36.dp, bottom = 30.dp),
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "One",
            Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .border(1.dp, Color.Blue),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(4.dp))
        Text(
            text = "Two is a bit longer",
            Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .border(1.dp, Color.Blue),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(4.dp))
        Text(
            text = "Three",
            Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .border(1.dp, Color.Blue),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]